# When answering my own question, why does having too many tags hide my answer on validation?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, self-answer

I just finished typing up a somewhat lengthy self-answered question and hit submit.  As I had 6 tags on my post instead of the allowed five, I was shown the validation error explaining this.

On that screen declaring I had too many tags, my shiny new answer was gone.

Imagine my horror.  Thankfully it was not *gone* gone; if I uncheck/recheck the "Answer my own question" box, the text pane for the answer does come back pre-populated with my answer.

Is this a bug?  If not, could someone explain the rationale to me?

Comment: I've encountered something similar, except I didn't load the page from a validation error but I loaded it from a draft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The state of the "Answer my own question" checkbox is now maintained across postbacks, so marking this as complete.

Comment: I can confirm I can no longer reproduce the problem in normal usage.  *However it still occurs if javascript happens to be disabled*.